# Use stringstream to read line of varying elements

Tags: c++

I have a file I need to read in that looks somethig like this:

```
1 2.23 Dove Body Wash
3 .50 Bic Pen

11 12.99 Tombstone Pizza
```

Where the field with the names of the products can have either only one word (Shampoo) or any number of words (Big mama's homestyle steak fries). The input file can also have blank lines, which I just need to skip over.

So what I have right now looks like this (using getline and stringstream):

This struct:

```
struct CartItem {
string  itemName;
int quantity;
double pricePerItem;

CartItem();
CartItem(string name, int qty,double price);
};
```

and then this code.

```
while (getline(itemList, inputline)) { //itemlist is my ifstream, inputline is a string declared.
    ss.clear();

    ss.str(inputline);
    ss >> item.quantity >> item.pricePerItem >> item.itemName;
    string word;
    while (ss >> word) 
    {
        item.itemName += " " + word;
    }

    if (ss.fail()) {
        continue;
    }

    else
        shoppingList.push_back(item);

}
sortItems(shoppingList, sortedList);
printReport(sortedList);
```

but it's not working (just crashing). If I replace the `while(ss >> word)` fragment with `if(ss>>word)` it works but I only get the second string from the file. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Just a suggestion: you could use `getline` on the `stringstream` after you have removed the quantity and price per item to get the remaining item name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide more details, e.g. what "just crashing" means. However, I think you have  problem with your logic.
`ss >> word` will be called on the final check in the while loop, when `ss` is already out of words, thus the word will fail to be extracted to `word` when the while loop exits, setting `ss`'s fail bit. Now, `ss.fail()` will always be true and you will never add items to your list.

I am guessing that you later rely on `shoppingList` having at least one item and this is the crash.

Try changing:

```
while (ss >> word) 
{
    item.itemName += " " + word;
}
```

to:

```
while (ss.good()) 
{
    ss >> word;
    item.itemName += " " + word;
}
```